# How can I control the behavior of a bootstrap carousel based on the behavior of an HTML5 video element?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement a Bootstrap carousel. The carousel will have slides which contain either videos or images. I would like to make it so that video slides stay active for the duration of the video (set to autoplay), and then continue with the default interval for images.

I have set up the carousel so that it contains four images and one video. I removed the code here for 3 of the images for simplicity. Without adding any additional Javascript, the carousel will cycle through images and video and the video plays with no problem. Because the default interval is set for all slides, the carousel moves onto the next slide before the video has completed.

Using some Javascript, I've managed to affect the interval, but I don't really understand the behavior, or if my Javascript even makes sense. Honestly, it's been a while since I've worked with Javascript.

```html
<div id="VIS-BBNALobby-C" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="/media/VIS-BBNALobby-M/aaa.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item vidslide active">
      <video class="d-block w-100" autoplay="" muted="">
        <source src="/media/VIS-BBNALobby-M/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $('#VIS-BBNALobby-C').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
        var slide = $('#VIS-BBNALobby-C').find('.active')
        if(slide.hasClass('vidslide')){
            $('#VIS-BBNALobby-C').carousel('pause');
        }
        while(!(slide.attr('ended'))){
            //waiting for video playback to end
        }
        $('#VIS-BBNALobby-C').carousel('cycle');
  });
</script>
```

I would like the carousel to pause the cycling until the video returns that playback has ended, in which case, cycling resumes. I believe what's happening instead is that the video plays, the carousel doesn't pause until the first shift to the next slide, and then it sits in a loop. It's hard for me to tell what's happening. I'm not quite used to debugging with a browser.

**Solution:** I went with the event suggestion made by 6502, although I wrote it a little bit differently, as seen on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_play.asp).

```
  var vid = document.getElementById("wedidit");

  vid.onplay = function() {
    $('#VIS-BBNALobby-C').carousel('pause');
  };

  vid.onended = function () {
  $('#VIS-BBNALobby-C').carousel('next');
  $('#VIS-BBNALobby-C').carousel('cycle');
  };
```

**Better Solution:** I was under the impression that the "data-interval" tag only worked on the carousel element, but it does in fact work for the carousel-item elements. I was able to just set the interval for individual items, making this much easier.

```html
<div id="VIS-BBNALobby-C" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" data-interval="1000">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="/media/VIS-BBNALobby-M/aaa.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="91000">
      <video id="wedidit" class="d-block w-100" autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="/media/VIS-BBNALobby-M/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "wait" like this in Javascript, you need to use events.

You need to attach a video end event to an handler that will resume the cycling of the carousel with something like...

```
addEventListener(video, "ended", ()=>('#VIS-BBNALobby-C').carousel('cycle'));
```

Comment: In that case, I should add two event handlers, right? One for 'onPlay' and one for 'onEnd' would make sense, right?

Comment: This worked, although I did the events a little differently. See my edit to question.